# Ranking by partition with a conditional expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the `RANK()` of profit between the years 2015-2016, ignoring the other rows. Here is what I have so far:

```
with SalesX as (
    select 'Office Supplies' Category , 2014 Year,22593.42 Profit UNION all
    select 'Technology', 2014, 21492.83 UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2014,   5457.73 UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2015,   25099.53  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2015,   33503.87  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2015,   50000.00  UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2016,   35061.23  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2016,   39773.99  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2016,   6959.95
) select *,
rank() over (partition by case when Year IN (2015, 2016) then 1 end order by profit desc) rank_in_2015_2016
 from SalesX order by rank_in_2015_2016
```

And the results:

[image]

However, what I'd like to grab is only the rank in 2015-2016, with every other year having a null ranking. So the correct results should be:

[image]

What would be the correct query to do this? Note, I'm looking to do this in the analytic expression, and not with something like a tacked on `CASE` statement at the beginning of it to conditionally nullify results.

Answer (score 2):

> not with something like a tacked on CASE statement at the beginning of it to conditionally nullify results.

The only way I see to meet such a requirements is below. No `case` involved :o)

```
select *, rank() over(order by profit desc) rank_in_2015_2016
from SalesX where Year IN (2015, 2016) 
union all 
select *, null
from SalesX where not Year IN (2015, 2016)
```

with output

[image]

Another option (trying to respect your requirement about `case` but below still can be considered as a little cheating :o) )

```
select *, if(Year IN (2015, 2016), 0, null) + 
  rank() over(partition by Year IN (2015, 2016) order by profit desc) rank_in_2015_2016
from SalesX
```

Comment: I am just noticing "no case involved" :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple filter flag column and a running row number / global rank can help out to calculate filtered RANK() or DENSE_RANK() in your case. You can look into the following query & modify accordingly based on your needs:

```
WITH
  SalesX AS (
  SELECT
    'Office Supplies' Category,
    2014 Year,
    22593.42 Profit
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Technology',
    2014,
    21492.83
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Furniture',
    2014,
    5457.73
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Office Supplies',
    2015,
    25099.53
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Technology',
    2015,
    33503.87
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Furniture',
    2015,
    50000.00
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Office Supplies',
    2016,
    35061.23
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Technology',
    2016,
    39773.99
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Furniture',
    2016,
    6959.95 )
SELECT
  Category,
  Year,
  Profit,
  CASE
    WHEN _filter = 1 THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY _filter ORDER BY rn)
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS _rank
FROM (
  SELECT
    Category,
    Year,
    Profit,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY profit DESC) rn,
    CASE
      WHEN year IN (2015, 2016) THEN 1
    ELSE
    0
  END
    AS _filter
  FROM
    SalesX )
ORDER BY
  _filter DESC,
  Profit DESC
```

Results:

[image]